# Why are numbers hard-coded like 1<<4 in HashMap.java class

Tags: java, hashmap, open-source

I was looking at the source code of HashMap.java at [this link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/07011844584f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java).

I came across a couple of pieces of code like this:

> static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4; // aka 16

and

> static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;

My question is, if these values have to be hard-coded, why not hard-code the evaluated values instead of these left-shift operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to emphasize the fact that they're powers of 2, must be powers of 2 and are an easy way to write powers of 2.

From the source code on Java 8:

```
/**
 * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
 */
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4; // aka 16

/**
 * The maximum capacity, used if a higher value is implicitly specified
 * by either of the constructors with arguments.
 * MUST be a power of two <= 1<<30.
 */
static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any good compiler will evaluate these expressions when compiling, and expression like these are easier for human to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

To show you which power of 2 in this situation.